# Detecting screen orientation change from service

Tags: android, service, screen, orientation

A pretty simple and straightforward question... is it possible for a service to detect screen orientation changes? If so, how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This link will answer your question: [How do I use a service to monitor Orientation change in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625167/how-do-i-use-a-service-to-monitor-orientation-change-in-android)

You can also create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for `Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` (`"android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED"`)

Answer (score -4):

Try this code

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.d("tag", "config changed");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        Log.d("tag", "Portrait");
    else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.d("tag", "Landscape");
    else
        Log.w("tag", "other: " + orientation);

    ... 
}
```

in android manifest file

```
<activity android:name="..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

Comment: This solution works in Accessibility service. You can override onConfigurationChanged() and detect changes in the service.