# Change home screen widget layout on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, homescreen, android-orientation

Is it possible to have a different layout on a home screen widget whenever orientation is changed? For example , when in landscape mode, I wanna show some textViews and ImageViews, but when switched to portrait, I wanna hide those textViews and only show ImageView, and the widget having a different size. Can this be done and how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5726776/2045570

Comment: Yes I searched that but in the xml part, it is on `<activity>`, My homescreen widget uses `<receiver>` so its a little bit different. Intellisense doesn't show  `android:configChanges=""` on my widget receiver on the manifest.

Comment: You can have a service that detects the orientation change. Found a good example. Let me know if this helps :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/4979026/2045570